# How to copy values from a pandas series in one dataframe, to a pandas series in another?

Tags: pandas

folks.

I have a problem where I am indexing some values in a dataframe, and trying to set the values of another dataframe where those indexes match.

For example, I have a timestamp:

```python
i = '2019-01-19 00:00:04'
```

I find the rows in the dataframe one where the timestamp matches:

```
values = list(df1.loc[i]['qc'].values)
```

Then, I look in a separate dataframe where there should be a corresponding series that has the same number of rows, and I try to set those rows to values

```
rawdata[rawdata.index == i]['qc'] = values
```

However, those values are not being set in `rawdata` to the corresponding values in `df1`.

Why?

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example of the problem? What does the rest of the data look like? What have you tried so far? What does the result you're expecting look like?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Are you using a `MultiIndex`? And are the dimensions of the two DataFrames identical (regarding the index and the `qc` column)?

Comment: No I am not using a multindex, but I figured it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using a different indexing method.

I did this with the following:

```
values = df1.loc[i, 'qc']

rawdata.loc[i, 'qc'] = values
```